# JSP no reconoce los servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en jsp con Netbeans (ya he desarrollado varios) pero en este a diferencia de los anteriores que he desarrollado he decidido organizar mucho mejor el código clasificándolo en carpetas (los archivos jsp dentro de la carpeta raíz que es la carpeta web) pero al realizar esto me doy cuenta que de esta manera no se reconocen los servlets. Hice la prueba moviendo uno de esos archivos a la carpeta raíz (web) y de inmediatamente al llenar el formulario reconoció el servlet. La pregunta es, ¿existe alguna manera para que reconozca los servlets y continuar con la organización del código? La verdad no quiero tener todos los archivos jsp en una misma carpeta por cuestiones de organización.

Answer (score 2):

Asegúrate de llamar a los servlets por su ruta absoluta, no su ruta relativa.

Ejemplo:

Estructura de carpetas:

```
src
  - edu.ltmj.servlets
    + MiServlet.java
web
  + index.jsp
  - WEB-INF
    - mi
      - carpeta
        - de
          + vista.jsp
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/MiServlet")
public class MiServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        request.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/mi/carpeta/de/vista.jsp")
            .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

index.jsp (omisión head y body para brevedad del código):

```html
<form action="/MiServlet">
    <label for="nombre">Ingresa nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <input type="submit" value="Saludar" />
</form>
```

vista.jsp

```html
Hola ${nombre}. Saludemos a alguien más.
<form action="/MiServlet">
    <label for="nombre">Ingresa nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <input type="submit" value="Saludar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque te faltan `jars` en la carpeta `lib` de tu proyecto. En concreto estos dos:

```
jsp-api.jar
servlet-api.jar
```

Los puedes encontrar en la carpeta `lib` de `tomcat`.
Si usas `maven` puedes hacer esto:

```
   <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```